# Macro - Copy CERTAIN Cells in Same Row, Triggered by a Checkbox, to Different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Need some assistance.  I have a template that gets data exported into it from a different program.  The rows of data varies from export to export and a new workbook is needed for each export.

I, currently, have a 'Master' macro written that cleans up the worksheet (formats, text to numbers, etc.) and also adds checkboxes to the end of each row that contains data.  These checkboxes are linked to a cell.  Once the operator completes the worksheet, they will then need to check a checkbox for each row of data that is 'out of spec'.  These rows will then be copied onto the next sheet in the workbook.  This is triggered by a button.  My current macro works other than copying the entire row of data when I only want to copy over cells in columns 'A' through 'I'.  Cells in columns 'J' and out contain data that does NOT need to be copied.

Here is my current macro that, like I said, copies the entire row:

```
Sub CopyRows() 
    Dim LRow As Long, ChkBx As CheckBox, WS2 As Worksheet
    Set WS2 = Worksheets("T2 FAIR (Single Cavity)")
    LRow = WS2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each ChkBx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If ChkBx.Value = 1 Then
            LRow = LRow + 1
            WS2.Cells(LRow, "A").Resize(, 14) = Range("A" & _
            ChkBx.TopLeftCell.Row).Resize(, 14).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the resize to 9 if you only want `A-I` to be copied

Comment: *Technically* you’re not copying the whole row right now, just `A-N`

Comment: I see...it just looked as if I was copying the entire row but, in reality, I was just copying the first 14 columns.  Thank you!

Comment: Would anyone mind reviewing the 'REVISED' macro above and letting me know what is wrong?  I'm getting an Excel VBA 400 error.  Thanks!

Comment: you're missing the colon `:` in the ranges (ex `Range("A1:B1")` )

Comment: Which line/range are you referring too, my man?

Comment: `WS2.Range("A" & LRow & ":I" & LRow) = WS1.Range("A" & r & ":I" & r + 1)` not sure that's the only problem but it stood out to me

Comment: it would also be good practice to `Dim r as long, WS1 as Worksheet` :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!  After revising per your advice, I no longer receive an error but it's now not copying anything!  LOL  Writing code is not easy, I'm starting to learn.  Revised the macro above to show where it currently sits.

Comment: Haha yeah it’s definitely a process! Hmm it could be that your new ranges don’t end in `.value`

Comment: If not, you might have to use the locals window and breakpoints (or whatever your preferred debugging method is) to make sure that everything is the proper value at each stage http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx

Comment: Am I allowed to swear on here?  LOL  I'll assume no and go with...You are the f'ing man!!!!  .value was the ticket.  Thanks again man!!!

Comment: Lmao glad I could help

Comment: If you moved your revision down below as an answer I’ll vote for it considering the effort you point forth :)

Comment: Man...I spoke too soon. LOL  Everything works great minus the last column of data.  Instead of falling in line with the data in cells "A:H", which starts in Row 19, all of the data in Column "I" is shifted up one row so it starts in "I18".  I played around with modifying a few things but no dice.  I'll revise the above macro to where I currently sit and add a screen shot if possible.

Comment: Can you reclip it to include column/row numbers?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Added a better screenshot.  Thanks again man.  Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help.

Comment: Not sure how i missed it before, but it looks like you're grabbing 2 rows instead of 1 each iteration. For the first part of each you just use `LRow` and the second you use `LRow + 1`, so I would say this fix would be `WS2.Range("A" & LRow + 1 & ":I" & LRow + 1).Value = WS1.Range("A" & r +1 & ":I" & r + 1).Value`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 You are now officially the F'ING MAN!!!!  Can't thank you, and the others who helped, me enough!  I'll move the newly revised macro below as an answer!!!  Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 1):

In the right-side of your equation, your `Range()` object is not properly qualified (with a worksheet). So, I used the fake `wsX` in this example.

Also, I used the ending column of "D" - but you can change to whatever you need it to be.

```
LRow = LRow + 1
r = ChkBx.TopLeftCell.Row

ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(LRow, "A"), ws2.Cells(LRow, "D")) = wsX.Range( _
            wsX.Cells(r, "A"), wsX.Cells(r, "D"))
```

or

```
ws2.Range("A" & LRow & ":D" & LRow) = wsX.Range("A" & r & ":D" & r)
```

---

> [From Comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053599/macro-copy-certain-cells-in-same-row-triggered-by-a-checkbox-to-different-wo/53054078#comment93027809_53054078)
>   *The templates ALWAYS start, with the imported data, in "A19". When I run this macro, to copy the checked data to the next worksheet, it starts in with cell "A18". I have no idea as to why. How do I specify that the checked data is to be copied starting with "A19" on the next worksheet?*
>
> > If it's always off by one, you can just add 1. I am not sure how your layout is, so this will be something you will have to either add to `LRow` or `r`. So either
> >
> > ```
> > ws2.Range("A" & LRow + 1 & ":D" & LRow + 1) = ...
> > ```
> >
> > or
> >
> > ```
> > ... = wsX.Range("A" & r + 1 & ":D" & r + 1)
> > ```

Comment: Thank you guys!!!  Still learning so your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I have one last question for you guys, if you don't mind.  The templates ALWAYS start, with the imported data, in "A19".  When I run this macro, to copy the checked data to the next worksheet, it starts in with cell "A18".  I have no idea as to why.  How do I specify that the checked data is to be copied starting with "A19" on the next worksheet?  Thanks again!

Comment: @K.Davis - THANK YOU for your service to our country!  That is appreciated above all!

Comment: Much appreciated, @TheBigEasy

Comment: Hey man, thank you for your help and your patience.  :)  Mind having a look @ my macro now?  I definitely have something screwed up because it's now not copying the checked data from worksheet ("T1 FAIR (Single Cavity)") to ("T2 FAIR (Single Cavity)").  I added my revised macro to my initial post.

Comment: @TheBigEasy the column `:D` was just an example. Did you update it to actually include the column you wanted? Also, which worksheet has the checkboxes? I would replace `.. in ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes` with `.. in wsX.CheckBoxes`

Comment: @K.Davis Yes, but I copied and pasted before the edit.  I edited the 'revised' macro above.  For this sheet, I need to copy over data in "A:I".  My bad!  When I run the revised macro above, I'm getting VP Error 400.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is as follows:

```
Sub CopyRows()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("T1 FAIR (Single Cavity)")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("T2 FAIR (Single Cavity)")

    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = ws2.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    Dim r As Long

    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox
    For Each ChkBx In ws1.CheckBoxes
        If ChkBx.value = 1 Then

            LRow = LRow + 1
            r = ChkBx.TopLeftCell.row

            ws2.Range("A" & LRow + 1 & ":I" & LRow + 1).value = _
            ws1.Range("A" & r & ":I" & r + 1).value

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it works properly now? I imagined that adjusting `LRow + 1` for both should expect you to also update `r + 1` for both instances

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Yep, this portion of the macro is working perfectly.  Of course, I now have other issues.  LOL  Sorry for the delayed reply, had Excel crash on me which led to macros being deleted and/or dissociated with their buttons.  Been a pain in the you know what.

Comment: Okay, great! Works for me then - gl fixing those issues!